# Private constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, private

I have an object of class which has private constructor:

```
class CL_GUIComponent
{
    // ...
    private:
    CL_SharedPtr<CL_GUIComponent_Impl> impl;
    CL_GUIComponent(CL_GUIComponent &other);
    CL_GUIComponent &operator =(const CL_GUIComponent &other);
    CL_GraphicContext dummy_gc;
};
```

I have a class which has a pointer to the object of the type I described before.

```
class Some
{
   private:
       CL_GUIComponent *obj;
   public:
       CL_GUIComponent getComp() { return *obj; }
}
```

But this code calls the error:

```
In member function ‘CL_GUIComponent Some::getComp()’:
error: ‘CL_GUIComponent::CL_GUIComponent(CL_GUIComponent&)’ is private
error: within this context
```

How can I store and get that object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return a reference instead:

```
CL_GUIComponent& getComp() { return *obj; }
```

and/or

```
const CL_GUIComponent& getComp() const { return *obj; }
```

The code you have their is trying to return a copy, but the copy constructor is private so it can't access it (hence the error). In any case, for non trivial objects, it's almost always better to return a `const&` instead (in general, not always).

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem since he clearly can't modify that function.

Answer (score 2):

By pointer or reference.  You can't construct a new one and thus can't return copies, as your get attempts to do.

Comment: I thought that I'm returning a reference, not the copy?

Comment: in c++ if you want to return an object by reference, you need to put `&` sign after the return type: `CL_GuIComponent& getComp...` as Peter Alexander shows.

Answer (score 0):

getComp returns an instance of CL_GUIComponent.  This means that getComp will actually make a copy of the instance pointed to by obj.  If you want getComp to return the instance where obj is pointing to, return a reference to CL_GUIComponent, like this:

```
CL_GUIComponent &getComp() {return *obj;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [**non-copyable**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-copyable_Mixin) idiom in action. Return by pointer or reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getComp()` to initialize a reference.

```
CL_GUIComponent const &mycomp = getComp();
```

Then the language doesn't try to invoke the copy constructor inside the calling function. (`getComp` does still create and return a copy, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the constructor is declared private, you have to use a public member function to create an object of class that uses the private constructor.

```
class CL_GUIComponent 
{ 
    // ... 
    private: 
    CL_GUIComponent();
    CL_GUIComponent(CL_GUIComponent &other); 
    CL_GUIComponent &operator =(const CL_GUIComponent &other); 
    public:
    CL_GUIComponent* CreateInstance()
         {
           CL_GUIComponent *obj = new CL_GUIComponent();
         }

};
class Some 
{ 
   private: 
       CL_GUIComponent *obj; 
   public: 
       CL_GUIComponent* getComp() { return (obj->CreateInstance()); } 
};
```